# How to add a Parsed JSON image from URL to imageView Dynamically?

Tags: java, android, json

I have the following code and i like to add my parsed JSON image from URL to my `ImageView` I don't know how to do it and my code is the following (I get responce and the other data go the desired TextViews):

DisplaySearchResultsActivity.java

```
package com.cloudlionheart.museumsearchapplication;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;



public class DisplaySearchResultsActivity extends ListActivity
{
    // Progress Dialog
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    // Creating JSON Parser object
    JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> museumItemsList;

    // url to get all products list
    private static String url_search_results = "http://10.0.3.2/android_connect/get_all_products.php";

    // JSON Node names
    private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
    private static final String TAG_MUSEUM_ITEMS = "museumItems";
    private static final String TAG_MUSEUM_ITEM_ID = "id";
    private static final String TAG_MUSEUM_ITEM_NAME = "itemName";
    private static final String TAG_MUSEUM_ITEM_ARTIST = "artistName";
    private static final String TAG_MUSEUM_ITEM_LOCATION = "itemLocation";
    private static final String TAG_MUSEUM_ITEM_HISTORICAL_PERIOD = "itemHistoricalPeriod";
    private static final String TAG_MUSEUM_ITEM_IMAGE = "itemImage";

    // products JSONArray
    JSONArray museumItems = null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_search_resaults);

        // Hashmap for ListView
        museumItemsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        // Loading products in Background Thread
        new LoadAllProducts().execute();

        // Get listview
        ListView lv = getListView();
    }

    /**
     * Background Async Task to Load all product by making HTTP Request
     */
    class LoadAllProducts extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        /**
         * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
         */
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(DisplaySearchResultsActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Loading Museum Items. Please wait...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        /**
         * getting All products from url
         */
        protected String doInBackground(String... args)
        {
            // Building Parameters
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            // getting JSON string from URL
            JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_search_results, "GET", params);

            // Check your log cat for JSON reponse
            Log.d("All Museum Items: ", json.toString());

            try {
                // Checking for SUCCESS TAG
                int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

                if (success == 1) {
                    // products found
                    // Getting Array of Products
                    museumItems = json.getJSONArray(TAG_MUSEUM_ITEMS);

                    // looping through All Products
                    for (int i = 0; i < museumItems.length(); i++)
                    {
                        JSONObject c = museumItems.getJSONObject(i);

                        // Storing each json item in variable

                        String item_id = c.getString(TAG_MUSEUM_ITEM_ID);
                        String item_name = c.getString(TAG_MUSEUM_ITEM_NAME);
                        String item_artist = c.getString(TAG_MUSEUM_ITEM_ARTIST);
                        String item_historic_period = c.getString(TAG_MUSEUM_ITEM_HISTORICAL_PERIOD);
                        String item_location = c.getString(TAG_MUSEUM_ITEM_LOCATION);
                        String list_image = c.getString(TAG_MUSEUM_ITEM_IMAGE);

                        // creating new HashMap
                        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                        // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                        map.put(TAG_MUSEUM_ITEM_ID, item_id);
                        map.put(TAG_MUSEUM_ITEM_NAME, item_name);
                        map.put(TAG_MUSEUM_ITEM_ARTIST, item_artist);
                        map.put(TAG_MUSEUM_ITEM_HISTORICAL_PERIOD, item_historic_period);
                        map.put(TAG_MUSEUM_ITEM_LOCATION, item_location);
                        map.put(TAG_MUSEUM_ITEM_IMAGE, list_image);

                        // adding HashList to ArrayList
                        museumItemsList.add(map);
                    }
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        /**
         * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
         * *
         */
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            // dismiss the dialog after getting all products
            pDialog.dismiss();
            // updating UI from Background Thread
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    /**
                     * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
                     * */
                    ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                            DisplaySearchResultsActivity.this, museumItemsList,
                            R.layout.list_item, new String[]{TAG_MUSEUM_ITEM_ID,
                            TAG_MUSEUM_ITEM_NAME, TAG_MUSEUM_ITEM_ARTIST,
                            TAG_MUSEUM_ITEM_HISTORICAL_PERIOD, TAG_MUSEUM_ITEM_LOCATION,
                            TAG_MUSEUM_ITEM_IMAGE},
                            new int[]{R.id.museum_item_id, R.id.museum_item_name,
                                    R.id.museum_item_artist, R.id.museum_item_historic_period,
                                    R.id.museum_item_location, R.id.museum_list_image});

                    // updating listview
                    setListAdapter(adapter);
                }
            });

        }

    }
}
```

and my other class

JSONParser.java

```
package com.cloudlionheart.museumsearchapplication;

/**
 * Created by CloudLionHeart on 5/7/2015.
 */
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.client.utils.URLEncodedUtils;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.util.Log;

public class JSONParser {

    static InputStream is = null;
    static JSONObject jObj = null;
    static String json = "";

    // constructor
    public JSONParser() {

    }

    // function get json from url
    // by making HTTP POST or GET mehtod
    public JSONObject makeHttpRequest(String url, String method,
                                      List<NameValuePair> params) {

        // Making HTTP request
        try {

            // check for request method
            if(method == "POST"){
                // request method is POST
                // defaultHttpClient
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
                httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                is = httpEntity.getContent();

            }else if(method == "GET"){
                // request method is GET
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "utf-8");
                url += "?" + paramString;
                HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                is = httpEntity.getContent();
            }

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            json = sb.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }

        // try parse the string to a JSON object
        try {
            jObj = new JSONObject(json);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }

        // return JSON String
        return jObj;

    }
}
```

Comment: What specific problem are you having?

Answer (score 1):

Using [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/):

```
 Picasso.with(context)
        .load(imageUrl)
        .into(imageView);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [image loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader) library to load image dynamically into imageview.
As it given easy documentation, just follow it. You have to pass url of image.

Comment: Can you please add an code example so it can run on my code? it seem that i can not access the image URL from my parsed JSON.

Comment: Can you post example of image URL you trying to load?

Comment: {"museumItems":[{"id":"1","itemName":"Mona Lisa","artistName":"Unknown","itemLocation":"Athens","itemHistoricalPeriod":"1503 - 1506","itemImage":"http:\/\/localhost\/image_folder\/mona_lisa.png"},{"id":"2","itemName":"test","artistName":"test","itemLocation":"test","itemHistoricalPeriod":"test","itemImage":"http:\/\/localhost\/image_folder\/scream.png"}],"success":1}

Comment: And this JSON response came from server?

Comment: yes it my schema i want to add the image from the URL i provide. It is a 2 ROW responce

Comment: Ok that means localhost is accessible in your device.

Comment: yes it is i can get all textView to work and update with this code except the imageVIew if i can fix this my app is finished.

Comment: Here I suggest you to use GSON for JSON parsing. And for loading images use universal image loader.

Comment: but how can i do this i tried all option on internet and nothing

Answer (score 0):

I Hope it will help  you..!

```
public class LoadImageFromURL extends AsyncTask{  
@Override  
protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... params) {  

try {
URL url = new URL("image-url");  
InputStream is = url.openConnection().getInputStream();  
Bitmap bitMap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);  
return bitMap;  

} catch (MalformedURLException e) {

e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
// TODO Auto-generated catch block
e.printStackTrace();
}
return null;

}
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
super.onPostExecute(result);
yourImageview.setImageBitmap(result);
}
```

}

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>  
add Permission into you manifest.
```

Comment: Can you please add an code example so it can run on my code? it seem that i can not access the image URL from my parsed JSON.

Comment: @TasosKaratzoglou, Have a look..1-http://javatechig.com/android/download-image-using-asynctask-in-android,2-http://androidexample.com/Download_Images_From_Web_And_Lazy_Load_In_ListView_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=112&aaid=134